Custom `Read` instance fails when type is wrapped in Max, but derived instance works - What's wrong with my Read instance?
(Why am I writing Positive32? See my previous question.)
Here's a module exposing a newtype for 32-bits postive integers:
module Positive32 (Positive32, positive32, getNum) where

import Data.Word (Word32)
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

newtype Positive32 = Positive32 { getNum :: Word32 } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Bounded Positive32 where
  minBound = Positive32 1
  maxBound = Positive32 (maxBound :: Word32)

positive32 :: Word32 -> Positive32
positive32 0 = error "Attempt to create `Positive32` from `0`"
positive32 i = Positive32 i

where I've derived Show out of habit, but that's nothing bad:
λ> positive32 3
Positive32 {getNum = 3}
λ> positive32 0
Positive32 {getNum = *** Exception: Attempt to create `Positive32` from `0`
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ...

Then I've realised I also needed a Read instance. However, I can't just derive it, otherwise the client has suddenly a way to wrap 0 into a Positive32:
λ> read $ "Positive32 {getNum = 0}" :: Positive32 
Positive32 {getNum = 0}

So I tried to write a Read instance "myself"¹:
instance Read Positive32 where
  readsPrec _ s = [(positive32 num, rest) | (num, rest) <- readP_to_S parsePositive32 s]

parsePositive32 :: ReadP Word32
parsePositive32 = do
  _ <- string "Positive32 {getNum = "
  num <- munch1 isDigit
  _ <- string "}"
  return (read num)

It seems to work for a very basic case,
λ> (read $ show $ positive32 3) :: Positive32
Positive32 {getNum = 3}

but it fails if I wrap the number in Max
λ> import Data.Semigroup (Max(..))
λ> (read $ show $ Max $ positive32 3) :: Max Positive32
Max {getMax = Positive32 {getNum = *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

whereas the derived Read class would handle this case well:
λ> import Data.Semigroup (Max(..))
λ> (read $ show $ Max $ positive32 3) :: Max Positive32
Max {getMax = Positive32 {getNum = 3}}


(¹) Quotes => ChatGPT came up with it; first time it gave me something that compiles, btw.

ChatGPT has here solved (rather awkwardly) the problem of reading representations of the exact form "Positive32 {getNum = }", but a Read instance needs to be more flexible than that. Ideally it should handle any literal form of Haskell code for the expression; not many instances actually do that but at least they need to handle variable whitespace. This one doesn't allow for any changes at all there, and that's what causes the failure: when reading the string
    "Max {getMax = Positive32 {getNum = 3}}"

your parser is given the control at
    "Max {getMax = Positive32 {getNum = 3}}"
                  ↑

so it sees
                 " Positive32 {getNum = 3}}"

and therefore first needs to discard a space before parsing the constructor. There's a standard way for doing this.
I would recommend that you make your Read instances also compatible with the non-record style of constructor. For example:
parsePositive32 = do
   skipSpaces
   string "Positive32"
   skipSpaces
   choice
    [ between (string "{getNum" >> skipSpaces >> string "=")
              (skipSpaces >> string "}")
              (skipSpaces >> simpleNum)
    , simpleNum
    ]
 where simpleNum = read <$> munch1 isDigit

Generally, I'd avoid defining Read by hand, as it's tedious and error-prone. Usually it's best to just stick to the derive instance. For Show it can make sense to define a custom instance if the derived one is impractically verbose, but it should still be compatible.

Generally, I'd avoid defining Read by hand, as it's tedious and error-prone. Usually it's best to just stick to the derive instance. I totally agree with the habit. But in this case deriving Read in principle means giving a client a clear way to misuse the type, thus challenging Hyrum's Law :P

@Enlico arguably yes, though abusing read to generate illegal values is almost as obviously a bad idea as using coerce for the same way. In practice, read should basically only be used to read values that come straight from show. If you want it really reliable, then you shouldn't export the Positive32 constructor and also not view it in the show instance.

Wait, I haven't exported the value ctor, but only the type ctor, so I'm not letting my client do pattern-matching. What's wrong with exporting the type ctor? Also, what does view it in the show instance mean?

I meant the value constructor. Whose name currently appears in the output of show.

But that doesn't allow client code to take advantage of it, no? It's not like had exported Positive32(..).
